# Wordpress Page Pagination IF query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

```html
<?php
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
   $pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>

<div id="page_nav">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Previous Work</a><span>/</span>
  <a id="back_link" href="http://kyleskelly.co.uk/#projects_container">Back to Projects</a><span>/</span>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>">Next Work<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

My knowledge of php isn't great, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**I want my code to query -**

**IF** is first page in portfolio then the a tag for prev link is inactive.

**else if** last page in portfolio then next page link is inactive.

**else** the code i already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this code, but I think it should work. Please let me know if something arises. I've commented the code to explain you more or less what I've done.

```
<?php
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$current = get_the_ID();// Current Page ID. I assume IDs are unique, and all pages have one. All the IDs are in $pagelist.

$next = $prev = FALSE;
reset($pagelist);// Pointer to first element.
while ($page = current($pagelist) ){// Loop through the array. I used while instead of foreach for its convenience to get next element.
    if( $page->ID == $current) {
        $obj = next($pagelist);
        $next = $obj ? $obj->ID : FALSE;// If there's a next, get the ID, otherwise we are the last page.
        break;
   }

   $prev = $page->ID;// Previous element
   next($pagelist);// Update pointer
}

?>

<div id="page_nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php if($prev !== FALSE) {// If I have a previous element, print out a ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Previous Work</a><span>/</span>
        <?php } ?>
        <a id="back_link" href="http://kyleskelly.co.uk/#projects_container">Back to Projects</a><span>/</span>
        <?php if($next !== FALSE) {// If I have a next element, print out a ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next); ?>">Next Work<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kyleskelly glad to help :) please accept the answer if the problem is solved